# TexStudio: Use dictionary for completion

Tags: texstudio, auto-completion, dictionaries

Is it somehow possible to extend TexStudio to use dictionary words in autocompletion?

For example, when I type "som", I want the autocompletion list to show me all words from the dictionary starting with "som". I know TexStudio uses autocompletion for words that already appear in the same document.

I've tried to create a .CWL file, but apparently it is only for commands and plain words are not supported.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Answer (score 1):

TeXstudio only has a command completion (based on the cwl files). There is no word completion (also not for words that already appear in the document).

You can however achieve something similar for fixed word lists [by scripting](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/texstudio/index.php?title=Scripts#Word_Completion).

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the scripting possibility. I'm afraid that the posted example of a fixed list is not exactly what I was looking for, because it always uses the first item in the list that starts with the given text. Is it possible via scripting to show the auto completion dropdown box and fill it manually?

Comment: No, it is not possible to access the completer via scripting.

Answer (score 0):

However, you can achieve it using the following tweaks. First convert the dictionary file to `cwl` file by adding `\` before each word, remove `/something`, e.g. `/SM` patter and add the that file to your configuration file, e.g. `~/.config/texstudio` in Mac OS X. Add this file in the preference panel of texstudio will enable you to get a list of words for autocompletion when you type `/`. However, when you select a word, an extra `/` will be shown in front of the word, as should be the case of a command. To remedy this, you can define a macro, e.g. trigger by `//` that remove this extra `/`. The macro to do this is

```
%SCRIPT
cursor.movePosition(1,cursorEnums.StartOfWord)
cursor.deletePreviousChar()
```