# Can the texmaker be configured so that it prompts words while writing?

Tags: texmaker, editors, spelling, dictionaries

I'm beginning to learn the use texmaker. I have enabled the texmaker dictionary. I wonder whether there is any option by which I can enable it to prompt or suggest words while writing.

Comment: I don't think your bounty will get you anywhere further than the "use a different editor" answer you've already gotten, if there are no options for it in the settings already, it likely isn't implemented, which means that you have to make a feature request to the developer (which, originally, is done via Twitter ...)  I could be wrong of course, but that was my first thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a very similar yet more powerful latex editor, texstudio, to achieve this (texstudio and texmaker develops from the same software yet follows different philosophy and routes, texstudio being more configurable, texmaker being more compact). For details, refer to my answer in [Use dictionary for completion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/164861/texstudio-use-dictionary-for-completion/239344#239344)